# Animate CAShapeLayer path change

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I'm trying to animate change of `path` property of `CAShapeLayer` like this:

```
animatePathChange(for: progressLayer, toPath: progressPath.cgPath)
progressLayer.path = progressPath.cgPath
```

And this is`animatePathChange`function code:

```
func animatePathChange(for layer: CAShapeLayer, toPath: CGPath) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    animation.duration = 1.0
    animation.fromValue = layer.path
    animation.toValue = toPath
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: "easeInEaseOut")
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "path")
}
```

But the end result is not what i want. How can i achieve animation that changes layer's `path` from old value to new?

This is how it looks right now with the code above:

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you animate the `strokeEnd` of the layer instead of changing the path?

Comment: This will animate paths drawing from start. I want to animate just the difference between old and new path along the path.

Comment: I don't know why but I laughed so hard at the animation. Thanks for the laugh

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Don't animate the path. Configure the whole path and then set the `strokeEnd` — let's say it's `0`, so the user sees nothing. Now each time you want to make a change, animate the change from the current `strokeEnd` to the new `strokeEnd`. The path will appear to extend further round the curve.

[image]

Comment: Why i didn't thought about this.. Thank's a lot!